# Como eu faço para mostrar o livro com maior quantidade de páginas?

Tags: java

Já tentei um monte de coisa e é só esta Opção `case 4` que é para mostrar o livro com maior quantidade de páginas que está faltando.

Se tiver alguém pra me ajudar nessa opção eu agradeço porque té difícil.

```
package projeto;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sistema {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Cadastro> vetor = new ArrayList<Cadastro>();
        int codigoDoLivro,paginas,qntdEmEstoque, opcao;
        String titulo,autor,categoria;
        double valorDoLivro;
        Cadastro cadastro;

        do {
            System.out.println("Segue lista de opções");
            System.out.println("1 - Cadastrar Livro\n" + "2 - Editar Dados Pelo Código\n" + "3 - Listar Livros por Categoria\n" + "4 - Livro com Maior Quantidade de Páginas\n" + "5 - Valor total dos Livros em Estoque\n" + "6 - Média do Valor de todos os Livros\n" + "7 - Sair");
            opcao = ler.nextInt();

            switch(opcao){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Entre com o Código do Livro");
                codigoDoLivro = ler.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Entre com a Quantidade de Páginas");
                paginas = ler.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Entre com a Quantidade em Estoque");
                qntdEmEstoque = ler.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Entre com o Nome do Livro");
                titulo = ler.next();
                System.out.println("Entre com o Nome do Autor do Livro");
                autor = ler.next();
                System.out.println("Entre com a Categoria do Livro (Ex: Administração, direito, ficção)");
                categoria = ler.next();
                System.out.println("Entre com o Valor deste Livro");
                valorDoLivro = ler.nextDouble();

                vetor.add(new Cadastro(codigoDoLivro, paginas, qntdEmEstoque, titulo, autor, categoria, valorDoLivro));
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Entre com o Código do Livro");
                codigoDoLivro = ler.nextInt();

                for (int i = 0; i < vetor.size(); i++) {
                    Cadastro aux = vetor.get(i);

                if(codigoDoLivro == aux.getCodigoDoLivro()) {
                    System.out.println("Entre com a Quantidade de Páginas");
                    aux.setPaginas(ler.nextInt());
                    System.out.println("Entre com a Quantidade em Estoque");
                    aux.setQntdEmEstoque(ler.nextInt());
                    System.out.println("Entre com o Nome do Livro");
                    aux.setTitulo(ler.next());
                    System.out.println("Entre com o Nome do Autor do Livro");
                    aux.setAutor(ler.next());
                    System.out.println("Entre com a Categoria do Livro");
                    aux.setCategoria(ler.next());
                    System.out.println("Entre com o Valor do Livro");
                    aux.setValorDoLivro(ler.nextDouble());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Nenhum Registro Encontrado\n");
                    }

                aux.print();

                }
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Entre com a Categoria");
                categoria = ler.next();

                for(int i2 = 0; i2 < vetor.size(); i2++) {
                    Cadastro aux3 = vetor.get(i2);

                    if(categoria.equals(aux3.getCategoria())) {
                        aux3.print();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Nenhum Registro Encontrado\n");

                    }
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                Cadastro teste = vetor.get(0);

                for(int i3 = 0; i3 < vetor.size(); i3++) {
                    Cadastro aux2 = vetor.get(i3);
                    if(aux2.getPaginas() > teste.getPaginas()) {
                        System.out.println("O Livro é: " + aux2.getTitulo());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Nenhum Registro Encontrado");
                    }
                }
                break;

            case 5:
                int soma = 0;

                for (int i=0; i < vetor.size(); i++) {
                    Cadastro aux4 = vetor.get(i);
                    soma += aux4.getQntdEmEstoque();
                }

                if (soma != 0){
                    System.out.println("O número de livros em estoque é: " + soma);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Nenhum Registro Encontrado");
                }

                break;
                case 6:
                double media = 0;
                int soma2 = 0;
                for (int i=0; i < vetor.size(); i++) {
                    Cadastro aux4 = vetor.get(i);
                    soma2 += aux4.getValorDoLivro();
                    media = soma2/vetor.size();
                }

                if (media > 0){
                    System.out.println("A média dos valores dos livros: " + media);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Nenhum Registro Encontrado");
                }

                break;

            }

       } while (opcao != 7);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Faltou atualizar o livro com mais páginas dentro do `if`, e o `else` também não faz sentido estar caso contrário a mensagem `"Nenhum Registro Encontrado"` pode aparecer várias vezes. Pelo mesmo motivo a mensagem do maior só deve ser mostrada após o `for` terminar.

Faça antes assim:

```
case 4: 
    if (vetor.size() == 0){
        System.out.println("Nenhum Registro Encontrado");
    }
    else {
        Cadastro maior = vetor.get(0); //assume-se que o maior é o primeiro

        for(int i3 = 1; i3 < vetor.size(); i3++) {
            Cadastro corrente = vetor.get(i3);

            if(corrente.getPaginas() > maior.getPaginas()) {
                maior = corrente;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("O Livro é: " + maior.getTitulo());
    }  
    break;
```

Repare que o `for` começa logo no `1`, pois se o `0` é inicialmente considerado o maior não há necessidade de voltar a testar esse elemento.

Para além disso alterei também os nomes das variáveis. As boas práticas de programação dizem que os nomes das variáveis devem ser evidentes e representativos do que elas guardam. Um nome como `teste` ou `aux2` pouco ou nada diz e torna o código difícil de ler senão mesmo enigmático. Imagine o que era atribuir como nomes de variáveis `a`, `b`, `c`, ... Nem mesmo o autor do código ira saber para que serviam passado uns tempos.

Quando tem variáveis com nomes repetidos ao longo do vários `cases`, como por exemplo o `i`, pode utilizar `{` `}` em cada `case` que resolve o problema, e evitar ter de inventar nomes alternativos.

Comment: muito obrigado pela explicação nunca me ocorreu nesse semestre todo da minha faculdade colocar um for no else.